# Typescript string union of object values as constants

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

If I have an array of objects, how can I get a property of each object and create string union of its constant value? For example, below I have the array `options`. I want to create a type like `type Values = 'firstName' | 'lastName' | 'email'`.

```
const options = [
  { label: 'First Name', value: 'firstName' }, 
  { label: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName' },
  { label: 'Email', value: 'email' }
] as const;

// Close, but not quite what I need
const values = options.map(x => x.value) // ("firstName"|"lastName"|"email")[]
```

Comment: You want a type or an array?

Comment: `type Values = (typeof values)[number];`? [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5zKVm)

Comment: I want the type. Thanks @caTS !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to retrieve the type by using `typeof` and indexing into the array type with `number`:

```
type Values = (typeof values)[number];
```

Please note that [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) behaves differently when used in this context. It gets the type of a variable; in this case it's `values` that has a type of `("firstName" | "lastName" | "email")[]`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5zKVm)